How to add interaction between endogenous and exogenous variables in a IV regression using feols?
I am using command feols from package fixest. I have two endogenous variables (x1_endo, x2_endo), four exogenous variables (x1_exo, x2_exo,x3_exo,x4_exo) plus one categorical variable (x_class) and four instruments (x1_inst,x2_inst,x3_inst,x4_inst).
I would like to interact x1_endo with x_class in the regression on the dependent variable (y).
I have tried
feols(y ~ x1_exo + x2_exo + x3_exo + x4_exo | 
        x1_endo + x2_endo + x1_endo:x_class ~ x1_inst + x2_inst + x3_inst + 
        x4_inst + x_class, data = data)

However, I am not sure wheter this is right. Is it?
I would like any help. Thanks.
